# Online Forms: Making Drop Down Box(es) Available When Check Box Selected

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I'm looking for some help with forms!  Having learned a decent bit of HTML and CSS, I'm still a bit of a newbie when it comes to forms and the server-side scripting behind them.  I hope my question is fairly self-explanatory, but to clarify what I am trying to achieve:

- I would to create a form with the options 'Default' or 'Custom' colors on check boxes (or radio buttons)
- If the user selects 'Custom' I would like a drop down menu to become available, with a list of the colors to choose from
- Ideally I would like the drop down box to be present in the form, but 'greyed out' (i.e. non-selectable) until 'Custom' is checked, rather than just appearing (although this is a 'nice to have')

My questions then, are 'what language would I use to achieve this? (i.e. PHP?)' and 'how!?'

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help me.  Obviously I'd like a solution that is 'good to go', but I'm happy to be pointed in the direction of further reading on the subject, as I like to learn and I just can't seem to find out what the 'right' language and learning is for this...

Jim.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to learn something about **javascript**, nothing to do with server-side language (i.e. PHP).

You have to watch for *selected* property for select boxes.

An important note, all things you have mentioned are client side, but when you will press OK on your form what will happen *after* depends on your server-side language. And here is when PHP become useful. However you only asked for something that is client like, so start studying javascript before anything else.

Good luck

Comment: Learning a framework like JQuery will make it less painful as your learning will not be hindered by browser differences (which you should go back and learn later).

Comment: I agree definitely with you, was thinking to the same thing